# RealmSwift update in URLSession-background-downloadTask callback

Tags: swift, object, realm, urlsession

Using Swift-4.0.3, RealmSwift-3.0.2, iOS-11.2.6 and Xcode-9.2

I try to update a Realm-object form a URLSession callback (`didFinishDownloadingTo`) - see code below. This callback is entered several times until a complete download of a file is done. To keep a persistent information on the download-status, I would like to use a realm-object.

For some reason this does not work yet. I get the following exception:

```
Main Thread Checker: UI API called on a background thread: -[UIProgressView progress]
PID: 7200, TID: 113132, Thread name: (none), Queue name: NSOperationQueue 0x60000023e8a0 (QOS: UNSPECIFIED), QoS: 0
Backtrace:
4
```

What is wrong ? (Also, dispatching to the main-queue or background did not help)!

```
extension DetailDBFileDownloaderViewController: URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    let downloadService = MyDownloadService()

    //... not all needed delegate-methods shown....

    // delegete method firing every time another chunk of a large-file has been downloaded...
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL) {

        // ...

        let tempDownloadEntry = DownloaderItem()    
        tempDownlaodEntry.identifier = self.someID
        tempDownloadEntry.someProperty = self.somePoperty
        tempDownloadEntry.DBFile.index = self.someOtherID
        tempDownlaodEntry.DBFile.moreProp = self.someotherProperty
        // ...    

        let entryRealm = try? Realm()

        if let rlm = entryRealm {

            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title == %@", self.titleLabelString!)
            let myTitles = rlm.objects(DownloaderTitleSet.self).filter(predicate)
            if (myTitles.count == 0) {
                // !!!! FIRST ROUND WORKS (i.e. Realm still empty) !!!!
                rlm.beginWrite()
                let newTitleSet = DownloaderTitleSet()
                newTitleSet.title = self.titleLabelString!
                newTitleSet.version = self.versionLabelString ?? "0.0.0"
                newTitleSet.lastItemIndex = self.someID
                newTitleSet.downloaderItems.append(tempDownloadEntry)
                rlm.add(newTitleSet, update: true)
                try! rlm.commitWrite()
            } else if (myTitles.count == 1) {
                // !!!! SECOND, THIRD, etc. round does not work !!!!!!!
                rlm.beginWrite()
                let existingTitleSet = myTitles.first

                // !!!!! Here is where the exception happens !!!!!!!!
                existingTitleSet?.title = self.titleLabelString!
                existingTitleSet?.version = self.versionLabelString ?? "0.0.0"
                existingTitleSet?.lastItemIndex = self.someID
                existingTitleSet?.downloaderItems.append(tempDownloadEntry)
                rlm.add(existingTitleSet!, update: true)
                try! rlm.commitWrite()
            }
        }
    }
    //...
```

In the same callback-method `didFinishDownloadingTo` (at the very end) - there is another download-task being initiated if the complete file-download is not finished yet (i.e. chunk by chunk downloading of a large file...). And therefore the callback-method `didFinishDownloadingTo` is called again and again ! And for every call - my Realm-object shall be kept persistant - adding a list-element...

```
    // ... the end of the didFinishDownloadingTo callback-method....
    if !allFileChunksDownloaded() {
        self.downloadService.startDownload(file: file, bytesRange: byteRangeString)
    }
}
```

And this is how the three realm objects looks like:

```
class DownloaderTitleSet: Object {

    @objc dynamic var title: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var version: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var lastItemIndex: Int = 0
    var downloaderItems = List<DownloaderItem>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "title"
    }
}

class DownloaderItem: Object {

    @objc dynamic var identifier: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var somePoperty: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var file: DBFile?

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "identifier"
    }
}

class DBFile: Object {

    @objc dynamic var index: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var moreProp: Int = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "index"
    }
}
```

How would I better do this ?

----- The background-task in question is an URLSession-DownloadTask and the delegate-method shown comes from the `URLSessionDownloadDelegate`callback.

The following code is really not relevant for this RealmSwift-Problem, I think, but for the people interested in the whole picture - here the call of the URLSessionDownload-Task that is executed and eventually will call the callback-method

```
// download-Service method starting the background-downloadTask
class MyDownloadService {

    var downloadsSession: URLSession!

    func startDownload(file: MyFile, bytesRange: String) {

        let download = MyDownloadTask(file: file)

        var request = URLRequest(url: file.previewURL!)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.addValue(file.accountAuthorizationToken!, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
        download.task = self.downloadsSession.downloadTask(with: request)
        download.task!.resume()
        download.isDownloading = true

        self.activeDownloads[download.file.previewURL!] = download
    }
}

class MyDownloadTask {

  var file: MyFile
  init(file: MyFile) {
    self.file = file
  }

  // Download service sets these values:
  var task: URLSessionDownloadTask?
  var isDownloading = false
  var resumeData: Data?

  // Download delegate sets this value:
  var progress: Float = 0
}
```

Comment: Is the problem the message about the main-thread-only API being called from a background thread? The code you've shared doesn't appear to use that API at all. Please share the relevant code, and any backtraces that show what is calling the API in question from a background thread.

Comment: The background task is an ordinary URLSession-downloadTask. The code I shared only shows the delegate-method (callback) from the URLSessionDownloadDelegate. It is quite hard to show all relevant code if it comes to threading, you know :). I can try to add some more code below my initial question, ok?

Comment: The main thread checker is complaining that the progress view is being touched on a background thread. None of the code you've shared does anything with the progress view AFAICT. Does the complete console message from the main thread checker include a backtrace? If so, share it.

Comment: Thank you very much, bdash, for pointing this out !Wow - indeed, it was a UIProgressView that messed things up! I needed to place every call to the progressbar inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async{...}` statement. Now it works. The thing that confused me is that this error always happend right at the spot where the realm is written to (and nowhere near the place in code where the progressbar is accessed)...